# Remove lines and print the average in csv with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, rows, average

I'm working on a python script that generates a csv file reading different columns from all the csv files I have in a folder. For now I generate the file and sort the columns.
The code that generates the csv is:

```
import csv
import glob
import os, sys

dirs = glob.glob('*.csv')

namelist = list(dirs)
timestamp = ['TimeStamp']
file1 = dirs[0]

for file in namelist:
    namelist[namelist.index(file)] = file.partition("TrendLogExtended_")[2].partition("-Ext).csv")[0]

primariga=[]
primariga.extend(timestamp)
primariga.extend(namelist)

print dirs[0]
print len(dirs)
print namelist[0]

primofile = csv.reader(open(file1, 'rb'), delimiter=";", quotechar='|')
output_rows = []

for row in primofile:
    output_rows.append([row[2]])

for file in dirs:
    data = csv.reader(open(file, 'rb'), delimiter=";", quotechar='|')
    column = []
for idx,row in enumerate(data):
    output_rows[idx].append(row[15])

with open("provaoutput.tmp", 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in output_rows:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open("provaoutput.tmp", 'r') as data_file:
    lines = data_file.readlines()
    lines[0]= ";".join(primariga) +"\n"
    with open("finale.txt", 'w') as out_data:
        for line in lines:
            out_data.write(line)
```

With this script I generate a CSV that looks like:

```
TimeStamp;TH;AM;RHNoEB
2014/08/27 11:15:19.658;;;
2014/08/27 10:15:26.060;52.51;24.51;19.23
2014/08/27 10:15:56.050;52.51;24.24;19.18
2014/08/27 10:16:26.060;52.48;24.89;19.45
2014/08/27 10:16:56.045;52.37;25.16;19.83
....
```

I sort this csv with another script that looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt('finale.txt', dtype=str, delimiter=';')
s = a[0].argsort() # produces the indexes which would sort the header
s = np.append(0, s[s!=0]) # put 0 at the front again, that's Timestamp
final = a[:,s]
np.savetxt('finale-2.txt', final, fmt='%s', delimiter=';')
```

I obtain:

```
TimeStamp;AM;RHNoEB;TH
2014/08/27 11:15:19.658;;;
2014/08/27 10:15:26.060;24.51;19.23;52.51
2014/08/27 10:15:56.050;24.24;19.18;52.51
2014/08/27 10:16:26.060;24.89;19.45;52.48
2014/08/27 10:16:56.045;25.16;19.83;52.37
....
```

So far so good. Now I have 2 problems. Some rows (like the second one) has just the timestamp without any measure. I would like to remove all this "empty" lines (what I mean is (sometimestamp;;;;;;;;'). How can I do it?

The second problem is that I would like to generate another csv calculating the average every 5 or 10 rows (X minutes). What I mean is:

```
TimeStamp;AM;RHNoEB;TH
2014/08/27 10:15;24.375;19.205;52.51
2014/08/27 10:16;25.025;19.64;52.425
....
```

The TimeStamp is not a big problem, I can use the timestamp of the first measure that I use to calculate the average.
Could you help me?

---

More info about the average.

On each row I have measures from different devices.
I would like to calculate the average every X measures (X rows) per device (per column, each device has its own column). X could be every 10 rows, or something like that.
The input csv is the one that I sorted and cleaned up with the previous script.

---

What I mean is:

```
timestamp1-1;5;4;2 
timestamp1-2;3;6;4 
timestamp2-1;4;2;1 
timestamp2-2;8;4;1
```

And obtain

```
timestamp1-1;4;5;3 
timestamp2-1;6;3;1
```

Comment: Could you make clearer your second requirement?
The other csv will be generate from the one you have previously created?

Comment: I added some info. Yes, I have to use as input the csv I generated and calculate the average every 10 rows for each column.

Comment: @GabrielButoeru, just use `if line.rsplit(";",1)[-1]:` to check

Answer (score 1):

to eliminate invalid timestamps you could use for example :

```py
with open("filetoclean.stats",'r') as input, open("cleanedfile.stats", "w") as output :
    for line in input:
        if not ";\n" in line:
            output.write(line)
```

This code copy all the line from a file that do not end with a ";" and copy them into another file. If this condition isn't enough to match you're requirement, you should consider the use of a regular expression.

*-- EDIT : ADDING ANSWER TO THE SECOND PART OF THE QUESTION --*

Concerning the average value of each column every X row, this code should work :

data=["timestamp1-1;5;4;2",
         "timestamp1-2;3;6;4",
         "timestamp2-1;4;2;1",
         "timestamp2-2;8;4;1"]

```
def add_values(tmp,values):
    if tmp == None :
        tmp = [0.0]*len(values)
    #sum values by pair of same index
    return list(map(lambda x,y : x+y, tmp, values))

def pretty_string(aList):
    return str(aList)[1:-1].replace(",",";")

def row_average(data, packsize):
    #initialisation
    row_count = 0
    tmp = None
    result = ""

    for row in data:
        index,text_values = row.split("-")
        values = [float(value) for value in text_values.split(";")]
        tmp = add_values(tmp,values)
        print(tmp)
        row_count += 1

        if row_count == packsize:
            #the map divide all the values of the list by packsize
            result += "{0}-{1}\n".format(index,pretty_string(list(map(lambda x: x/packsize, tmp))))
            print(result)
            tmp = None
            row_count = 0

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = row_average(data, 2)
```

I used little sub-function to make it more readable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The empty lines are not that empty ... What I call empty line is a line that looks like timestamp;;;;;;;; ... It contains';' but no measures

Comment: the ";\n" match any line that end with a ";" as "\n" is the end of line character. This eliminate any line without the last part. `"2014/08/27 10:15;24.375;19.205;52.51"` do not match, but `2014/08/27 10:15;24.375;19.205;` match it. This is a simple test assuming that you have only good i.e. complete line, or line such as `timestamp;;;;;`. If not, regular expressions should be your friend.

Comment: Ok, that works like a charm. I just edited it because it prints 'line' not the line, but thanks :) . Now I just have to figure out how to calculate the average :(.

Comment: edited to correct bug. And could you add more information about average ? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to pass data as with open('finale-2.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')

but it says "I/O operation on closed file". Why?

Comment: Without any code to reproduce the bug I cannot help you. This code : `with open("foo.txt", 'r') as csvfile:
  data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ";", quotechar="|")
  for line in data:
   print(line)`
works on my computer. Do your code is correctly indented ?

Answer (score 1):

This should compute the average and ignore the lines with not measurements

```
with open('your_csv', 'rb') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        if i == 0: continue
        s_l = l.split(';')
        last_3 = s_l[-3:]
        if all(last_3):
            last_3_floats = map(float, last_3)
            avg = sum(last_3_floats )/len(last_3_floats)
            print s_l[0] + ';' + str(avg)
```

P.S not tested

Comment: could not convert string to float: AM

I have to skip the first row I think, because the headers are not decimal or float

Comment: It does something but not what I'd like.
It calculates the average per row.
If my row is timestamp;3,4,5 it print timestamp;4

What I would like to have is:

timestamp1-1;5;4;2
timestamp1-2;3;6;4
timestamp2-1;4;2;1
timestamp2-2;8;4;1

And obtain

timestamp1-1;4;5;3
timestamp2-1;6;3;1

Comment: I edited the question so you can see what I mean in a less chaotic way